# cant add/ update news with image in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

controller

```
<?php
class Breaking extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('breaking_model');
    }
public function create_breaking_news()
     {
        $this->securePage();

        if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', ' Breaking News Title', 'required');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('details', ' Breaking News Details', 'required');


                if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

                    $added_on = time();



                    // if image is uploaded
                    if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size']>0) {
                        $config['upload_path'] = $this->config->item('upload_path');
                        $config['allowed_types'] = $this->config->item('allowed_types');
                        $config['max_size'] = $this->config->item('max_size');
                        $config['max_width'] = $this->config->item('max_width');
                        $config['max_height'] = $this->config->item('max_height');
                        $config['encrypt_name'] = $this->config->item('encrypt_name');

                        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                        if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
                            $image = $this->upload->data();

                            $this->breaking_model->add_news($image['file_name'], $added_on);
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<button class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%;">The Breaking News has been added successfully.</button>');
                            redirect('breaking/manage-breaking-news');
                        } else {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $this->upload->display_errors());
                            redirect('breaking/create-breaking-news');
                        }

                    } else {
                        // if image is not uploaded
                        $this->breaking_model->add_news(null, $added_on);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<button class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%;">The About Breaking News been added successfully.</button>');
                        redirect('breaking/manage-breaking-news');
                    }
                }
            }

        $data['news_title'] = 'Add Breaking news | Kanchan news.com';
        $data['Keywords'] = '';
        $data['url'] = '';
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('breaking/create', $data, true);
        $this->load->view('kanchan', $data);
     }
}
```

my models

```
function add_news($image, $added_on) {

            $this->db->set('title', $this->input->post('title'));

            $this->db->set('details', $this->input->post('details'));

            $this->db->set('video', $this->input->post('video'));

            $this->db->set('images', $image);

            $this->db->set('added_on', $added_on); 

            $this->db->insert('breaking_news');
        }
```

and my view

```
<div class="container">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="active"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('full_name');?></li>
        <li class="active">Breaking News</li>
        <li class="active">Add Breaking News</li>
    </ol>
    <?php echo $this->session->set_flashdata('msg');?>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title"> Enetr Breaking News Title :</label>
            <hr>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('title');?>">
            <?php echo form_error('title');?>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title"> Enetr Breaking News Images :</label>
                    <hr>
                    <input type="file" name="userfile">
                    <?php echo form_error('userfile');?>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title"> Enetr Breaking News Video Url( not required) :</label>
                    <hr>
                    <input type="video" name="video" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('video');?>">
                    <?php echo form_error('video');?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title"> Enetr Breaking News Details :</label>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="ckeditor" name="details"><?php echo set_value('details');?></textarea>
            <?php echo form_error('details');?>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">Add Breaking News</button>
    </form>


    <hr>
</div>
```

i can add data without image successfully but when i select image it wont added data and redirect too create page  without any error message  and same problems with update too